# How many App Domains are Created

Tags: asp.net, .net, appdomain

I am going through how ASP.NET page is processed when the request is send from browser to Server. From many sources i came to know that during asp.net request processing  Application Manager instance is created and the Application manager creates the application domain . The Application domain provides isolation layer with in the process. My Question here is for the same application if there are many requests coming up , will all the requests will be processed by same App Domain or it will create many App Domains for each request. How to calculate how much memory the Application Domain is using. Will the App Domains share the dlls if many App Domains are using the same references like (system.web, system)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/103516/does-every-asp-net-web-application-has-a-single-application-domain